# functional testing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing

I have testing code as follow, why "test "should get create" do" always failed????

```
  # called before every single test
  def setup
    logger.debug '2'
    @new_user = User.create(:email                 => 'shrimpy@email.com',
                            :password              => 'secret',
                            :password_confirmation => 'secret')
    logger.debug "==========> #{@new_user.id}"
  end

  # called after every single test
  def teardown
    @new_user.delete
  end



  test "should get create" do
    logger.debug '1'
    get :create, :email => "shrimpy@email.com", :password => "secret"
    assert_response :success  # <------why it always failed here?
    assert_redirected_to user_path(@new_user)
  end
```

Console output:
    Finished in 3.834383 seconds.

```
  1) Failure:
test_should_get_create(SessionsControllerTest) [test/functional/sessions_controller_test.rb:24]:
Expected block to return true value.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

test.log:
    2
      SQL (2.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'shrimpy@email.com') LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.0ms)   SELECT name
     FROM sqlite_master
     WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
      AREL (6.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "hashed_password", "salt", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('shrimpy@email.com', 'b4e991c44d9738effa3
    98e97d7ed1e6ccad19c90ce2e911344a21bf9c82f915f', '258003960.04544115923816805', '2011-04-21 07:04:00.891929', '2011-04-21 07:04:00.891929')
    ==========> 980190963
    1
      Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"email"=>"shrimpy@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
      User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'shrimpy@email.com' LIMIT 1
    Redirected to http://test.host/users/980190963
    Completed 302 Found in 166ms
      AREL (0.0ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 980190963
```

This is the function i am testing:

```
 def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to user_path(user), :notice => 'You have successfully login'
    else
        redirect_to login_url, :alert => "Invalid email/password combination"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the response isn't success, the response is a redirect.

Understanding this requires a little understanding of HTTP, and a little understanding of what `assert_response :success` and `redirect_to` do.  All that `assert_response :success` is testing is the HTTP response code, it's testing to see whether it's a success code.  You get a success code when you render a page back to the browser.  When you redirect you **do not** get a success code, you get a redirect code instead.

So if you want to check the response you *could* use `assert_response :redirect` - although this is redundant when you already have the `assert_redirected_to`

Read more [here in the Rails guide for testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers)